# Is "to satisfy a connection" idiomatic in the mentioned text?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> We need a process in which A and B are properly connected. The process
>   X **satisfies** such connection.

Is "to satisfy a connection" used in the above sense idiomatic? Other similar option is "meet".

Comment: I think the process satisfies the _requirement_, not the _connection_.

Comment: Or *Process X establishes the requisite connection between A and B.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So "establish" is your top choice? What about "draw"?

Comment: No, **draw** is not correct. "to draw a connection" is to **infer** something.  The verb **make** would also do instead of **establish**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So establish is the most idiomatic verb for connection in the mentioned sentence?

Comment: **establish** is an idiomatic choice.

Answer (score 1):

Things that can be satisfied are wants, urges, needs, and rules.

Requirements, decrees, edicts, laws, commandments, convenants, regulations typically fall in the "rules" category.

*Connection* won't typically be something that can be directly satisified unless through context it's something that "wants."  If you are doing system programming for TCP/IP, you might speak of a program "satisfying" a connection to prevent it from timing out, but otherwise you wouldn't say "satisfy a connection."

Comment: So what is the  right verb for connection?

Comment: You say “satisfies the requirements for connection.”

Comment: What about "maintains/holds such connection"?

Comment: Maintain means something different than satisfy.  Maintain means to do something to keep something going, whereas satisfying might happen in order to start something *or* keep something going.  Two terms are not really synonymous.

Comment: What about "draw such connection"?