# "such a view" or "one such view"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

1. > We need a view that explains X. The next chapter proposes **one such view.**
2. > We need a view that explains X. The next chapter proposes **such a view**.

Which one of the above is more idiomatic?

Comment: such a view sounds odd here. one such view is better English in this context.

Comment: @Lambie You might like to take a look at this question too: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150238/is-to-satisfy-a-connection-idiomatic-in-the-mentioned-text

Comment: I don't need to do that to answer your question. The best written/writing style here is "one such view". You can use "such a view" but it is not the most elegant. Don't you want to sound elegant? :)

Answer (score 3):

They are both equally idiomatic, with two issues that need to be corrected:

--your verbs need to agree in number with the subject:

> a view that **explains** X...
>
> chapter **proposes**

and

--an article is required before "next":

> *The* next chapter proposes

Comment: Thanks. You might like to answer this unanswered question too:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150238/is-to-satisfy-a-connection-idiomatic-in-the-mentioned-text

Comment: @user157323: I  left a comment on that question a few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

They are both nice idiomatic expressions, as Tromano says. To get into the very slight differences in connotation: **one such view** perhaps emphasises the fact that the proposal is only one possibility of many. **Such a view** also implies that it's not the only possibility, but puts a little less stress on the fact. So, in some contexts, **one such view** could be construed as involving a bit more **hedging** - like, "I'm not claiming it's the most correct or the optimal, but..."